# Determinant of a mixed rank-2 tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, covariance

Often dispersion relations in plasmas are found by setting the determinant of some quantity to equal zero. My question is, **how does one do this when working covariantly with tensors** ([e.g. Broderick, A. and Blandford, R. 2003](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0302190)).

Taking an example from the linked paper (Eq. 74), suppose we have some mixed rank-2 tensor $\Omega^{\mu}_{\nu}$ that we want to find the determinant of. The indices $\mu,\nu$ run $0,1,2,3$. If,

$$ \Omega^{\mu}_{\nu} = (k^{\alpha}k_{\alpha} +\omega_p^2)\delta_{\nu}^{\mu} - k^{\mu}k_{\nu}$$

then how would one find det $\Omega^{\mu}_{\nu}$?

Comment: see [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

Comment: Ok great - that is useful for my example given. Thanks! But what about for a more complicated expression where we have two rank 2 tensors?, e.g. $\Omega^{\mu}_{\nu} = \alpha \delta^{\mu}_{\nu} - i \gamma M^{\mu}_{\nu}$ (eq. 76)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Perhaps? I posted it here as it is a question I came across whilst reading a physics paper, and thought others may have similar queries from a physics perspective.